# Can't Find an specific Query in DB SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with CPU performance, with SQL profiler we find that a query like

```
SELECT * FROM SPOT
```

Is running with all the CPU, but we can't find'em trough all the SP's, Views, etc..

Is there a way to find that query without opening one-by-one file in the SERVER?

I tried to filter by folders in SSMS but not get the results.

The profiler just got the name of the query, time, cpu used but not the file or location

Comment: Have you considered a user is running this query, or perhaps it's being passed directly by an application?

Comment: Yep, there's no app using Spot tables or something, it could be a SP or a View but we have like hundred of files

Comment: You could try `SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE N'%SELECT * FROM SPOT%';`

Comment: Dan! Thanks a lot, it works! Just  need to change the search condition, instead of put all the query, just use the target object like [dbo].[SPOT]